# how to successfully use lists in android?

Tags: android

I have a little problem with Lists in android. For example I have made an android application. In this application I query the elements of my list but everytime I get the last element when I show it with System.out.println.

### MY MAIN_ACTIVITY:

```
package djukic.tests.list;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import djukic.tests.list.TagData;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        returnTG();
    }

    public List<TagData> returnTG ()
    {
        List<TagData> list =new ArrayList<TagData>();
        TagData t1 = new TagData();
        TagData test = new TagData();

        for(int i=0; i <= 2 ; i++)
        {   
        t1.setName("Motor" + i);    
        list.add(t1);
        }

        System.out.println("list size = " + list.size());
        test = list.get(0);
        System.out.println("test.getName 2 = " + test.getName());
        test = list.get(1);
        System.out.println("test.getName 2 = " + test.getName());
        test = list.get(2);
        System.out.println("test.getName 2 = " + test.getName());
        return list;

    }
}
```

### AND MY TAGDATA.JAVA:

```
package djukic.tests.list;


public class TagData 
{
    String name, last, tagID;
    int repetition, sollAmount, lastAmount;

    public TagData()
    {

    }

    public TagData(String name, int repetition, int sollAmount, int lastAmount, String last, String tagID)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.repetition = repetition;
        this.sollAmount = sollAmount;
        this.lastAmount = lastAmount;
        this.last = last;
        this.tagID = tagID;
    }


    //get Methods
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int getRepetition()
    {
        return repetition;
    }

    public int getsollAmount()
    {
        return sollAmount;
    }
    public int getlastAmount()
    {
        return lastAmount;
    }

    public String getlastDate()
    {
        return last;
    }

    public String getTagID()
    {
        return tagID;
    }


    //set Methods
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setRepetition(int repetition)
    {
        this.repetition = repetition;
    }

    public void setsollAmount(int sollAmount)
    {
        this.sollAmount = sollAmount;
    }
    public void setlastAmount(int letzteAmount)
    {
        this.lastAmount = letzteAmount;
    }

    public void setlastDate(String last)
    {
        this.last = last;
    }

    public void setTagID(String tagID)
    {
        this.tagID = tagID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really more of a Java issue.

You only create one TagData object, and you add the same object to the list each time. You're modifying the name for this one object.

You could, for example, change this:

```
List<TagData> list =new ArrayList<TagData>();
TagData t1 = new TagData();
TagData test = new TagData();

for(int i=0; i <= 2 ; i++)
{   
    t1.setName("Motor" + i);    
    list.add(t1);
}
```

to this:

```
List<TagData> list =new ArrayList<TagData>();

for(int i=0; i <= 2 ; i++)
{
    TagData t1 = new TagData();
    t1.setName("Motor" + i);    
    list.add(t1);
}
```

I suggest you read up on Java objects and references and the difference between pass by value and pass by reference.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show a possible solution, but as I mentioned, I recommend that you read up on how java works with objects and references to objects.

Answer (score 0):

what about changing

```
{   
   t1.setName("Motor" + i);    
    list.add(t1);
}
```

to just

```
    {
        list.add("Motor" + i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<TagData> list =new ArrayList<TagData>();
    TagData t1 = new TagData();
    TagData test = new TagData();

    for(int i=0; i <= 2 ; i++)
    {   
        t1.setName("Motor" + i);    
        list.add(t1);
    }
```

Instead of using the same object and changing the name over and over again, create a new object every time you wan tot add one to the list.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i+)
{
    t1 = new TagData();
    t1.setName("Motor" + i);
    list.add(t1);
}
```

This way, t1 will point to a new object every time you iterate.  Your example will simply rename the same t1 object over and over again, never reassigning it.